# Android canvas isn't showing

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I'm creating an Android game (basic game), and got stuck with displaying certain image on a canvas.
The game intention is to press the image and the image will change it's location.

I've made sure all the methods are written properly and image resource does exist.
The other questions which relates to "canvas isn't showing" here didn't assist me because my game doesn't involve any XML (yet).
I've followed this guide:
https://www.androidauthority.com/android-game-java-785331/

This is the my GameView class which suppose to create the image:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
        characterSprite = new CharacterSprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avdgreen));
        characterSprite.draw(canvas);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);
        characterSprite.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

My CharacterSprite class:

```
    public CharacterSprite(Bitmap png) {
        image = png;
        x=100;
        y=100;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 100, 100, null);
    }
```

The Image should appear on the screen, yet all I get is blank screen.

Thanks.

Comment: which "other question here" do you mean? If you link it, please edit your question accordingly

Comment: meant all other questions which relates to "android canvas isn't showing"

Comment: THe missing piece here is: where in your code do you "add" this View to the view hierarchy and how.

Comment: in MainActivity: setContentView(new GameView(this));